# installing ubuntu on acer failed

Tags: acer

I have used pendirvelinux (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to install Ubuntu on another computer, but when I boot the computer this pops up:

'default boot device missing or boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key then select BOOT MANAGER to schoose a new boot device or to boot recovery media.'

What can I do? I removed Windows from the computer, so it's currently without a operating system(?). Has the Ubuntu I installed been removed or is it just hidden?

cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed Ubuntu 17.04 and now can't boot at all: Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I think Windows file not be deleted.can you please tell us how do u install the ubuntu os ? did u create partition for Ubuntu setup or along with Windows?

but, try the following first>>>

1 ) Power on your machine 
 2) Enter into BIOS Settings
 3) Goto "Boot" Tab
  4) Highlight Boot Mode, press Enter, swap from "UEFI" to "Legacy Support".  Under that Swap UEFI to legacy First
 5) goto EXIT tab and highlight Exit saving changes . Press Enter.
Restart Your Laptop.

Comment: I installed ubuntu by using an USB with pendrivelinux. I'm not completely sure if i created a partition or not, by I clicked a button to remove all of windows. Tried the legacy support-option but it still wont boot.

Answer (score 0):

You see the Md5sum hash of ISO, and is the correct?

If the Hash is ok, try to use this step method-
1-format the usb with a slow option to rewrite all with 0.
2- Then mount the usb partition and proceed to burn the ISO on USB.
3- Boot and press the key option to enable Bios settings (F12, F2,F11 ... depend the models and brand of pc)  to see if the option to boot by USB is enabled if is not , change the option to yes and press F10 or the key to save changes.
4 - Proceed with boot process and if need press the key option to choose the usb to boot (F12 - navigate to usb and enter) , and then  launch boot with usb.

Also You can use the dd method to burn the ISO to your USB for example -
dd  if=/path/to/your.iso of=/dev/sdx (x= your target usb - maybe is sdb...)

Answer (score 0):

First if you have UEFI shift it to legacy support.

the simplest way is to remake the live pendrive and checking it for checksum, usually you can using live linux pendrive to do that else few other softwares are there, check them out.

Comment: I switched to legacy support, but this message pops up:

"PXE-MOF exiting PXE ROM
no bootable device -- insert boot disx and press any key"