# Installed Ubuntu 17.04 and now can't boot at all: Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, acer

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 from a USB on my Acer Spin 5 which came with Windows 10. I made the choice of removing Win10 because earlier when I Dual-booted Ubuntu and Windows 10 I was not able to boot into Ubuntu after a Windows update.

Now when I start my computer it says

> Default boot device missing or boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key, Then select "boot manager" to choose a new boot device or to boot recovery media

If entering this I only get the choice of booting with Windows Boot Manager which takes me back to this screen again, I'm also able to use my live-USB with Ubuntu and either load into Ubuntu live or install directly, both this options brings me back to the "Default boot device..." after a reboot. I've also tried boot repair with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

But now after reboot I get

```
Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found 
Failed to load image \EFI\grubx64.efi: Not found
 start_image() returned Not found

Failed to open "\EFI\BOOT\Microsoft\grubx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\BOOT\grubx64.efi Not found 
start_image() returned Not found
```

How do I solve this problem with not being able to get into Ubuntu?

[Boot repair summary](https://paste2.org/YtmankZH)

How do I know which partition is my main partition? 
Running

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gives

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1553670144 bytes, 3034512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F2E8B05E-6E0D-493F-9FF1-9F5D1195680B

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 GiB, 4002910208 bytes, 7818184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b571474

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 3142655 3142656  1.5G  0 Empty 
/dev/sdb2       3118960 3123567    4608  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Edited the post, I have already used the "Recommended Repair" at this time

Comment: Every Acer we have seen needs you to enable a UEFI Supervisory password and from within UEFI drill down to the grub/ubuntu .efi boot files in the ESP and enable trust. Details on password & trust setting:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Comment: This seems to be the solution @oldfred, I can now boot into Ubuntu. Do you mind putting it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every Acer we have seen needs you to enable a UEFI Supervisory password and from within UEFI drill down to the grub/ubuntu .efi boot files in the ESP and enable trust.

This seems to be unique to Acer.
But better than many other systems that require working around limits built into UEFI to only Boot Windows.

More details on password & trust settings:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

[Acer video on setting Supervisory Password](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29349/).