# i installed Ubuntu on an acer laptop, and only windows recovery shows up

Tags: boot, windows-10, acer

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an acer laptop, and after a successful installation I hit reboot now, and now only Windows 10 recovery appears with error code 0xc0000225. when I try to set the hard drive as the boot drive, only windows recovery appears. Reinstalling changed nothing, setting the hard drive as the first boot option also did not fix it. 
I am lost, any ideas?

Thank you all so much

Comment: What is the procedure you installed ubuntu?(along side or something else)? try installing grub through live CD.

Comment: I used a usb stick and followed the install instructions on there

Comment: First recover your MBR for windows from recovery and ...follow these instructions this one is tested to work.
http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Comment: If UEFI, you have to set UEFI supervisory password and enable trust. Applies to all Acer models. https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 & Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

If windows recovery is showing up then that means you did not allocate the entire drive to Ubuntu. You must have used the remaining drive space to install Ubuntu "alongside" Windows.

If you only want to have Ubuntu installed on the machine then you need to go back and install it without installing it alongside Windows. This will wipe the entire drive so that you do not see Windows at all. It is the second option listed in the picture attached (click on the link ->) 
[Ubuntu Installation options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSPfv.png)