# Installed ubuntu on machine with preinstalled win10 and now all is broken :(

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

2 days ago, i installed ubuntu for the first time, i installed it on acer es1-332 laptop, and i used option erase and "install ubuntu", what happend next? i cannot boot linux from "hard drive", it show no device, as a live from pendrive it work fine, i tried disable/enable secureboot, after use "boot-repair" bios show linux as "windows boot manager" i found on some forum becouse i erased pre-installed windows, i erase uefi as well, so stuff i know not work (installation ubuntu again, boot-repair) only solution that i found there is change to legacy boot, but i couldnt find anything like that in my bios option. i am a newbie on linux, i so i need your help guys

i dont care about windows i just need ubuntu machine.

Comment: All Acer require you to enable UEFI password and "trust" from within UEFI on .efi boot files.  If you reinstalled in Legacy mode, not sure. Some also have needed update to latest UEFI from Acer. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348269 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238

Comment: hmm but problem is that my not even have a option in bios to add trust file

Comment: See oldfred's references for a proper fix. As a short-term workaround, you might be able to disable Secure Boot and use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive to boot. Chances are a true fix will be easier, though.

Comment: Some older posts seems to be missing trust option. But upgrades to UEFI from Acer fixed that. But you have to set UEFI password to get UEFI to open up more settings/options. also see: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: hey Rod.rEFInd is amazing soft, i let me open it without changing uefi, but maybe someone know how to change it permanently in ubuntu-mate? i found some guide here but is to kubuntu and i am not sure its same or not.
http://gnu-linux.org/how-to-permanently-add-linux-entry-in-uefi-menu.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to try:

- Make sure secure boot is off, it can't boot otherwise
- It seems obvious, but try reinstalling ubuntu, try the advanced mode to fiddle around with partitions. Make sure there's a swap partition, root partition and maybe a boot partition ([Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation))
- Try using a different program to write ubuntu to your flash drive and make sure to confirm the checksum is the same as the one on the website.

Hopefully this helps (it probably won't)