# Can't install Ubuntu 16.04 from bootable USB (dual boot)

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10, usb-installation

I've been trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 64 bit.
I've burnt the iso image into a USB stick (with Rufus) and disabled fast boot and secure boot and changed the boot order but when I restart the computer it still boots to Win10.
What should I do now so that I can boot the USB.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate what machine you're using. On some machines, within the BIOS, there are two places to change boot order. Make sure all of those settings are correct.

Also, if you have more than one USP port, you cant try a different one.

Comment: I'm using an Acer Aspire E1-572PG. But I only find one place in the BIOS where I can chagne the boot order. And I also tried all the USB ports when booting.

Comment: Make sure you have newer UEFI from Acer, some threads mention downgrading UEFI, but newer ones say newest UEFI from Acer works: All Acer have the trust requirement: Acer Spin 5 Ubuntu 17.04 Needs Acer password & trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 Acer Aspire ES (15 ES1-523-844Y)  works with some settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364018

Comment: I've updated the BIOS, set the supervisor password, but still nothing.