# Installation freeze at GRUB2 on Acer TravelMate Spin B1 B118-RN-P7XQ

Tags: grub2, system-installation, acer

When installing Ubuntu on my Acer TravelMate Spin B1 B118-RN-P7XQ the installation stops/freezes when installing GRUB2.
When I then reboot the notebook (so the installation is not complete) I get to the GRUB2-command-line, where I can boot Ubuntu manually. However, every attempt to fix GRUB freezes the notebook.

This is the case with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with and without getting updates at installation time and Ubuntu 17.04 without getting updates.
Only when installing Ubuntu 17.04 WITH updates during installation time, the installation still freezes, but I can then boot right into Ubuntu. (However I doubt the installation is very usable/stable because of the incomplete installation...)

One possible workaround is to first install Ubuntu 17.04 with updates, then installing another Ubuntu with `ubiquity -b` (no bootloader), in which case the installation successfully completes.

Things I have tried:

- using another distribution: Ubuntu GNOME, Linux Mint, Antergos (with GRUB2); always the same
- calling Acer customer support: they switched the motherboard (?) and basically told me that they don't support Ubuntu, Ubuntu is not compatible (yet), and I should switch to Windows 10
- installing Antergos with systemd-boot instead of GRUB2, installing Windows 10; both work fine

This notebook comes with Endless OS, a strange Linux distribution, preinstalled (I can also successfully reinstall it). It also uses GRUB2 (Acer apparently has made it work on that distro).

Did I make any mistake?
If not, can I help somewhere to fix this problem, e.g. by providing (hardware-)information and/or testing? I'm not using the notebook actively, there is no data on it, so it might come handy.

Update 1: `sudo parted -l` after installing Ubuntu 17.04 with updates:

```
Model: ATA Micron_110_MTFD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   256GB  256GB  ext4
```

Update 2: https://paste2.org/9175MVMI
Also, `boot-repair` get's stuck at reinstalling GRUB...

Update 3:
diff, left is Ubuntum right is EndlessOS: https://www.diffchecker.com/d1QXLt5a

Update 4:
Error still occurs with Ubuntu 17.10.1 (though workaround exists).

Comment: Is this an UEFI install? Acer Spin 5 Ubuntu 17.04 Needs Acer password & trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238
 Or is it an older BIOS install? If UEFI you need gpt partitioning and then the ESP - efi sytem partition for grub to install. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred It is UEFI. But I have disabled SecureBoot to eliminate this potential issue (Acer-support said it is okay). GPT partitioning is done automatically by the script, but yes, it includes the ESP-EFI-partition.

Comment: @oldfred At which point should I run `sudo parted -l`? (before/after installation, 16.04/17.04, with/without updates, or after second installation for the workaround)

Comment: Whatever is most current. It was more to confirm whether MBR or gpt(UEFI). Are you installing Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode?, Grub will error in BIOS mode on gpt drive as it needs a bios_grub for BIOS boot. But you want UEFI boot. Have you updated UEFI from Acer? Acer Spin 5 Ubuntu 17.04 Needs Acer password & trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238
& Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: @oldfred I've added the result from `parted`. Yes, I'm installing in UEFI boot mode. Yes, UEFI is the latest version (1.05). I have Acer password set. I have tried adding ubuntu grub as trusted, that didn't help with the problem on older versions. On the latest version booting is not a problem anyway, only the installation is freezing.

Comment: All installs will use same /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP - efi system partition. The only change is a 3 line grub.cfg that is a configfile to load the full grub.cfg from an install. I have installed several versions & not had issue with just editing the 3 line grub.cfg to boot older install. And then grub will boot all installs it finds after `sudo update-grub`. If you have able to boot, I would think it is a full install. Often with newer hardware you need newest kernel, drivers & support software that newest distribution has, or older version just does not work well.

Comment: It seems that it is not a full install. Just tried `apt-get upgrade`, it got stuck at configuring grub-efi-amd64.

Comment: Lets see more details on install: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I've added the pastebin link to the question.

Comment: Have you set an UEFI passwork and enabled trust on /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi? You also have grub installed in MBR for BIOS boot, but grub will not correctly install on gpt for BIOS without a bios_grub partition. And you have mount of efi/UEFI partition in fstab, so you are configured for UEFI boot. This indicates that trust is not set: `Boot0000* Unknown Device:` as you would set a name like ubuntu for it. See 4th comment above for users who actually have Acer (I do not) and had to set trust.

Comment: @oldfred I have set a UEFI password and disabled SecureBoot, since it makes no difference if it is enabled and I add grubx64.efi or if I disable it (just retried it). The other thing I find strange, I thought there is no MBR on a GPT-disk?

Comment: MBR is only used by BIOS for boot code and partition table info. Gpt has a protective MBR, just so old partition tools see drive as fully formatted. Gpt should have one MBR entry saying entire drive is gpt partition. But then gpt has all the details of actual partitions. Best to use shimx64.efi to boot. One Acer user said he had to have Secure Boot on and shim is for UEFI Secure boot.

Comment: @oldfred I've reinstalled EndlessOS (works with and without SecureBoot, with or without trusting) and run `boot-info`, I've added a link to a comparison. Also I've noticed I can't add/delete boot-entries with `efibootmgr`, I get segfault or access violation errors. I don't think this is normal, is it?

Comment: This is Ubuntu forum, & we know nothing about EndlessOS. It looks like you now have BIOS boot using bios_grub partition. A normal ESP os FAT32 not FAT16, although supposedly FAT16 is allowed for external devices. And if BIOS boot then efibootmgr errors probably are to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost 4 years later, I checked if Acer had released a BIOS-update. That was the case (I had 1.05 which was the latest at that time, the current version is 1.28 from 2018). With the updated BIOS no more errors occur.

The workaround by LiveWireBT did its job in the meantime though.

Small note in case anyone has the same problem: since I'm using Ubuntu I don't have Windows installed on that machine, but the BIOS update is an .exe file. It was sufficient to create a bootable install USB-stick for Windows 10, copy the .exe file onto it, boot from it, go to repair options, commandline, and execute the .exe file. Make sure that you have a drive installed and the power plugged in, otherwise the program will refuse to update the BIOS. I guess that is a simpler/ approach than trying something with WINE.

Answer (score 1):

If just installing the grub package proves to be the issue and you can remove the drive to put it in another computer, then do just that and install Ubuntu there. Make yourself familiar with working around missing UEFI NVRAM entries, there are several ways to approach this, and you should have a bootable system when you mount the drive again. If the storage is just one (or more) soldered chips to the mainboard then you would need another drive to install on another computer, boot up a live disk on the target computer configure the partition table, copy all the contents of root and the EFI system partition with `sudo rsync -av` and configure `/etc/fstab` for the correct UUIDs. Some people would prefer some disk dump/clone but I prefer this one. With UEFI you wouldn't even need to call grub for modifications to the MBR if the proves to be the part where it crashes.

That would solve your problem by thinking outside the box. ;) Investigating the problem further would be a good idea. Endless OS is based on Debian if I recall correctly, it's not *strange*, it's actually very nice and has some advantages (no bad or stuck updates, steam via flatpak). It's worth a second look, don't write it off just because it's made for non-tech savvy people.

Comment: It's a M.2-SSD but I don't have another system with a M.2-Slot. I'll try installint on another drive and update here when I'm done. I don't think Endless OS is bad either, but I definitely don't see myself as its target-audience.

Comment: This worked quite well, everything seems to run fine. Ubuntu is doing some hardware-checks during installation, do I have to expect problems, because I'm using it on different hardware now?

Comment: @Mat2095 That is unlikely. The Linux kernel has almost all drivers except proprietary ones (that can be installed through the restricted driver menu) and I have yet to come across hardware that requires special configuration or additional packages to be detected during installation (there are special Ubuntu images for licensed hardware like Dell's Sputnik, though these customizations should be upstream and available for everyone in later releases). It should be fine.