# Freeze at install grub2 for installing ubuntu on Acer Travelmate Spin B1

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, acer

I'm not able to install ubuntu on a Acer Travelmate Spin B1. Every time the installation freezes at installing the grub2 package. The issue is the same as here: [Installation freeze at GRUB2 on Acer TravelMate Spin B1 B118-RN-P7XQ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946886/installation-freeze-at-grub2-on-acer-travelmate-spin-b1-b118-rn-p7xq). But I'm not able to take out the SSD.

What I did:

- Created a USB boot stick with Rufus
- Disabled secure boot in the UEFI
- Booted the stick (grub2 shows up) and select install ubuntu

  1. Tried to install "normal"
  2. Tried to install "extended" by creation the partitions on my own

Nothing worked.

Every time it gets stucked at:

```
x86_64-efi will be installed for your platform
```

The same error occurs when installing debian stretch. Does it work if I install ubuntu without grub2 (how?) and then maybe use SuperGrub2Disk to repair?

Edit 1:

I did what is described here: [How to prepare a disk on an EFI based PC for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu) and here [GRUB2 failed to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/865872#865872), means:

- Created a boot usb with gparted
- Created the partitions

  - 500 MB FAT32, label boot, esp
  - 5000 MB linux-swap
  - 20000 MB ext 4
  - 100000 MB ext

Then I started a ubuntu live stick and opened a terminal and run

```
sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1
```

Installed ubuntu from this live usb stick. Installation get freeze at point "install package grub2". New message in the terminal is

```
g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from Acer? Some need chkdsk if Windows or dosfsck if Ubuntu on the ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32. See this for details: change sdXY to your partition, often sda1, but varies. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/865872#865872

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. During several trial and errors I removed all partitions. But your link was leading me to this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu So I will do this first and then try your proposal.

Comment: I tried (see edit) everything from my comment below. But still no pogress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a Windows USB Boot stick with Rufus in UEFI Mode (GPT)
- Install Windows with this stick
- During installation remove all existing partitions and let Windows create the new ones
- Start Windows and udpate the  BIOS to 1.10
- Create a Ubuntu Live USB Stick with Rufus in UEFI Mode (GPT)
- Install Ubuntu from this stick

Comment: This was the solution