# Boot repair report. Can I get this interpreted?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

So I dual booted my Windows 10 with ubuntu and it worked for the first few days, but now I can only use ubuntu and gets stuck initiating Windows 10. It gets stuck in "Initiating automatic repairs loop".

I ran boot-repair but the problem continues. This is the link to the info returned:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25772569/

I hope you can help me, this is driving me crazy.

Thank you!!

Comment: You changed Windows .efi boot file to grub. That is not recommended as when Windows does its updates it replaces that file. With Acer all you have to do is set trust on ubuntu boot files (the unknown device line 558). You show a second Windows boot Manager entry, can you get to that in UEFI boot menu to directly boot Windows? https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 & details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: When I used boot-entry to try to fix the problem, when I turned on the pc after it had created a whole new lot of options to boot from, none of the Windows ones worked. If I turned the pc off and and turned it on again pressing f8 it let me choose two windows options, but they're names were identical. Those two didn't work either.
I'll try what you suggested. I'll post what happens

Comment: One of the Windows entries should directly boot Windows. It shows it is using bootmgfw.efi which is the Windows boot file. The other entry was created using grub. See lines 853 & 854. If boot 0004 does not boot Windows then you have Windows issues not related to Ubuntu/grub.

Comment: How do I change the Windows boot out of the grub? I enabled trust on ubuntu files and it appers on the boot priority list, but I have no problems with ubuntu. I need to boot Windows, but all of the options get stuck at the Acer logo and the 'repairs' loop.
When I turn on the computer, automatically the grub menu appears and lets me choose Ubuntu, Windows boot manager or the all other options boot-repair enabled, but none worked. Neither booting from UEFI boot menu (note that only two windows boot managers appear and are identical). Is there any other thing I could try?

Comment: I booted n°4 and the same, diagnosing and now "trying to do repairs", al always like the other options. I'll post on super user and see if it's a Windows related issue. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Batubuntu have you tried this? https://www.easeus.com/resource/fix-preparing-automatic-repair-loop.html

Comment: The incorrect "Windows Boot Manager" was 0003 in report. Using Ubuntu terminal: Confirm it still is 0003 with `sudo efibootmgr -v` and then delete it with `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` where XXXX is the 0003 or whatever that line is now. You want line that has grubx64.efi in description. See also `man efibootmgr`.

Comment: @brndn2k I just did and it doesn't work

Comment: @olfred I think I did what you told me to, but still does not work