# Grub Rescue message for Dual Boot system Windows 10 + Xubunto 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, windows

I am introducing to Linux and I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 following these guidelines ( https://www.muycomputer.com/2016/04/25/windows-10-y-ubuntu-16/ ).

Everything went smooth but when typping *sudo update-grub2* the Terminal never showed something like "found windows 10" or similar.

I could use both systems but had to change in the BIOS the UEFI mode to Legacy whenever wanted to go to Xubuntu (it never appeared in the Booting device option from BIOS or F12).

I have tried many many things but none of them worked but made it worse. Now in Legacy mode I go directly to "grub rescue" message and can now just run Windows 10 by activating UEFI (or using the Live USB Xubuntu). Not even the boot-repair worked because it warms that i am in Legacy mode.

The boot-info link is the following one: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QjcyCZ4cxS/

And my partitions system is the following:

[image]

I re-installed Xubuntu but the Grub-rescue messaged kept showing. I cannot boot on Xubunto anymore (but from USB LIve).

What should I try next? Is there any way to fix this from windows 10? 
Any clue on how to delete everything regarding to Xubuntu and start fresh?

Thanks in advance and any help to make me understand this partition scheme and grub system will be very much welcomed.

BTW I am happy windows partitions are still working perfectly, would be happy to keep that working :*|

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Or from grub you can only boot other systems installed in same boot mode. May be better to turn off UEFI secure boot. And better to use Boot-Repair to uninstall grub-pc (BIOS) and install the UEFI version. You must boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. And if Acer you need to enable "trust" and in Windows turn off hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Acer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238