# "Try Ubuntu" menu appears after installation on Acer Aspire ES 11-131 - without live USB I get "no bootable device"

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, uefi, acer

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire ES 11-131 laptop.

I choose to **Erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu**. My laptop was way too slow in Windows 10, so I just wanted to get rid of it.

My problem is that whenever I switch on the laptop the Ubuntu GRUB menu doesn't show the Ubuntu OS. It only shows

```
Try Ubuntu
Install Ubuntu
OEM install
disc repair
```

If I boot without the live USB I get `no bootable device found`.

I have installed in UEFI mode only and have run boot repair, clicked **recommended repair** but it didn't fix the problem. Boot repair said

> Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on `sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` file

[New boot info summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9JDFcZjKBx/)

[Old boot info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Crtz9GB6kw/)

[image: UEFI menu]

Comment: Run boot repair again, and get the info summary, and [edit] your question to include it. See possibly [Installed Ubuntu 17.04 and now can't boot at all: Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found](//askubuntu.com/a/909238) [Install Ubuntu on unbootable Acer Aspire E5-575 "Default Boot Device Missing or Failed."](//askubuntu.com/q/948328)

Comment: According to [oldfred's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238) you need to enable the supervisory password first (don't lose it...) - after doing that you might be able to "Select an UEFI file as trusted" and boot repair wants you to select the shim one

Comment: anjanik012 answer helped me out. Thank you so much for quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Secure boot from under Boot Tab.

- Go to the **Security** tab and look for **Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing** and select enter
- Navigate to `shimx64.efi` and press enter.

Might be something like this.

[image: Security menu in UEFI settings]

Save changes and exit. Now you should be able to boot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77627/discussion-on-answer-by-anjanik012-try-ubuntu-menu-appears-after-installation).