# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not booting after Installation

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, bootloader

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but it does not boot. The Error on the screen is 'Default Boot Device Missing or boot failed'. Secure Boot is enabled and Boot mode is Uefi.

### edit:

Now after the error shows up I get to a menu where I can select LinplusLite. After another error I can select ubuntu, then the system boots fine. Here is the link to the boot-repair output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NJfxXBZqfK/

The output of

`sudo efibootmgr -v` looks like this:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Jp42SY89pB/

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on line 861 of the boot-repair file?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did I've edited my question.

Comment: I see mention of Acer, is this an Acer system. They all have unique requirement of "trust" in UEFI. Acer Spin 5 Ubuntu 17.04 Needs Acer password & trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238
 & Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003