# Can't boot from hdd after usb install

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I recently decided to format and reinstall ubuntu on my laptop, for various reasons. I used a bootable usb stick, and followed a guide on how to boot from the key with grub, because after I deleted the Windows partition (I had a dual boot ubuntu-windows, with just Windows 10 initially) I could just access the boot manager that wasn't able to detect the usb key.
On the grub command line, I typed

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
```

which was the usb key partition. After that, I typed the exit command and I accessed the boot manager, and was able to boot from the key. During the installation process, I chose to erase the disk. 
Now, I can boot from the usb key only, even though I made sure that ubuntu is indeed installed. I tried to boot using the grub command line

```
set root = (hd1,gpt2)
linux /vmlinuz
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

but when I do, it gives me the error: No init found. Target system doesn't have /sbin/init

If you need more info about the error or in general, I will provide you.

Edit: right now I have 2 partitions, /dev/sda1, the EFI partitions, and /dev/sda2 where the actual os is stored

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
  But your second line probably should be `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2`

Comment: @oldfred I followed your suggestion regarding the linux /vmlinuz command and I managed to boot to Ubuntu. However the problem persists since whenever I unplug the usb key, it's not able to find any bootable device. So I used boot-info: here's the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kZsFPbqHP9/

Comment: Is error from UEFI, or from grub and you get grub>? What brand/model system? Install looks like standard UEFI install and UUIDs & GUIDs look consistent. You are showing unknown device in UEFI boot options which is typical of Acer. And then you have to enable "trust" on those entries and Update UEFI from vendor. You can also houseclean UEFI entries with efibootmgr. See `man efibootmgr` for trust: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238

Comment: @oldvendor if you mean the error I get when I try to boot without usb key, then no, the grub doesn't even appear. As for the error I described in the question, I don't get that anymore thanks to your suggestion. So, aside from the trust issue, aren't there any problems with UEFI?

Comment: What brand model system? Have you updated UEFI. After you update UEFI, you may have to change settings again that you did before. BIOS always reset everything. UEFI may reset some settings & save some, depending on vendor/UEFI.

Comment: Acer Aspire E5-575G-70G3. I watched the video for enabling trust but it assumes I can access bios and I can't, it asks me for a password I don't know. I'll try using efibootmgr

Comment: If you have fast boot on in UEFI, you may not have time to press any key. And fast start up in Windows needs to be off. But both Windows & Ubuntu have ways to reboot into UEFI. I think live installer has the 'System Setup' boot which is to UEFI.