# Dual booting Windows and Linux on separate drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I tried to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Acer Predator laptop with a i7 9th gen processor.

The installation seemed to finish succesfully, but when the system wasrebooted, GRUB didn't appear. The system straight up boots into Windows.

When I tried to access Linux from the boot manager (by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>), it showed Ubuntu but still just loads into Windows. Also, during installation, it didn't detect Windows and said that no OS was currently installed in this system.

Comment: Acer typically need UEFI update & if SSD firmware update. And Acer usually needs a "trust" setting in UEFI for "ubuntu" entry, often shown as unknown until your set trust. You also need Windows fast start up off to be able to see any NTFS partition from Linux. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Trust: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot