Dual boot windows/ubuntu in Acer no GRUB showing up
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows 10 on Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro. The main problem is that I cannot boot to the installed system, after the installation and removal of the pendrive regular Windows is still loaded.
I have prepared a bootable USB pendrive using Rufus 4.5 with GPT partition scheme and GRUB 2.12. Previously I shrunk my main disk to allocate 25 GB primary volume as it is shown in many tutorials. My computer uses UEFI boot mode, I have disabled secure boot and the priority of booting devices is set to start from HDD, then Windows boot manager, etc.
Notes: after the installation and the pendrive removal I was not able to boot to the newly installed Ubuntu as regular Windows booted immediately afterwards. I do not have the option to disable fast start-up, it doesn’t appear in the power settings where it should be. No ubuntu OS in the boot priority list whatsoever.
I have tried to launch boot-repair when booting to ubuntu again with the pendrive which happened to fix some errors but in the end still states
Locked-NVRam is detected. Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.02 LTS entry
Google shows answers like make sure you have UEFI boot mode and disabled secure mode (which I do). Still do not quite understand what’s happening, here is the link to boot-repair output.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rFZmQ9RQVZ/
I am confused as it seems that boot-repair tried to reinstall grub on different partition sda5 (during the initial ubuntu installation grub was placed to sda2 where windows boot manager lives). What am I missing out and could you please help to make grub finally show up?

Should have been an EFI install as that is what Windows is using. Grub did not see the Windows OS to make the menu for the 2 OS.

Thank you for the answer! Could you please elaborate on that? What do you mean by EFI install (is that the wrong bootable I created)?

Look how to make an EFI boot disk with Rufus for complete instructions.

While bit older model, is this how you installed? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Does Acer still require "trust" setting in UEFI to enable ubuntu entry. All older models have required trust setting. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742  Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx

@oldfred Thank you so much!!! It did solve the problem, you nailed it! It was Acer specific security thing, I am so relieved and grateful:)

@David to clarify for someone who might as well come across - the described process prepares the boot disk properly, the issue was with Acer Trust settings

Just to consolidate "trust" into a more recent answer for Acer systems.
Acer seems to be the only vendor that requires trust setting, but most models if not all models require it.
Best to download manual from Acer for your model system for details.
You have to enable "trust" setting in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot mode).
You typically have to have Secure boot on to get to setting, but can turn it off later. If you have to set password for UEFI, be sure to never lose that or reset to blank. Many older Acer also required UEFI firmware (InsydeH20 setup utility) update & SSD firmware update. Users should update to latest for security reasons anyway.
Acer's UEFI to get into more settings:
CtrlS
page Security
"Set Supervisor Password" press ENTER (never lose this password)
"Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing:" press ENTER
a new page appear with listed drives:
Drill down into ESP, EFI, ubuntu and find shimx64.efi.
Set as trusted and name "ubuntu" or whatever you want.
You can use shimx64.efi whether UEFI Secure Boot on or not.
F10 to save and exit
Above from these:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742
How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home
Installed Ubuntu 17.04 and now can't boot at all: Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found
