aging Aspire no boot device found
I have reviewed several of the provided 'AI' links and did not find a solution. So a question for the ACER Afficianados out there er here. I am currently working on an Acer v3-551-8887 as listed on the bottom tag or if I enter the snid, the unit is an Aspire A715-42G. So are these one and the same?  Anyhow,  the build date on this unit is from 2012.  So no secure boot and crude efi.  Which, I can get to boot after imaging by using the f12 key and selecting efi ubuntu. Wahla, not so instant kubuntu 24.04.  Is anyone aware of this model has a bios update that might fix this or a hack, that can do the same.  (I hesitate to do a bios update for the latter do to the possibility that the former is different).
This unit is running an:
AMD A8 4500M @ 1.90 Ghz with onboard Radeon graphics version ACF050VER015.015.001.042529.  System bios is 1.02.
8GB Ram sport'n a Toshiba Spinner MQ01ACF050.
tia

If booting in UEFI, you probably need an UEFI firmware update. Acer published several for most models. If 2012 that is early UEFI as Microsoft required vendors starting in 2012 to use UEFI with gpt partitioning and release of Windows 8. Check Acer support site for your model. Acer's need "trust" after install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518065/dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-in-acer-no-grub-showing-up Older but should be similar: Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

The current bios does not have secure boot.  Will and update enable/add that functionality?  I will go back to acer support and for another machine that has the exact same issue.
