Ubuntu won't boot after install no partitions
I used Windows in the past, but now I have decided to change and install Ubuntu myself. I made a live bootable media with Rufus for the latest Ubuntu version. After finishing the installation it tells me to restart. Then I can use it for that time, but after that restarting it or closing it and reopening it fails.
There is no partition or anything I can find in the boot menu. It said, "Reboot and select the proper boot device". I have selected my HDD for priority and also I have tried manual partitioning.
What should I do? I can't just install Linux at this point. I have also tried Fedora and the same issue. So any detailed help would be great.
It's an Acer and I do go and change it in the bios setting but I can only find window boot manager ,DVD reader, removable device and lan there
Thanks

What brand/model system? Some only want to default to Windows and you have to go into UEFI/BIOS system settings (not boot menu( and change boot order there.

@oldfred it's acer and I do go change it in the bios setting but I can only find window boot manager ,DVD reader, removable device ,lan there

Acer is unique and requires you to enable Secure Boot, and Control S to get more menus. And then enable "trust" on the "unknown" entry as Ubuntu. Aspire V 15 Nitro Trust settings required.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518065/dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-in-acer-no-grub-showing-up
Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx
