Ubuntu 24.04 Fails to Boot Acer Aspire E5-574G
OS to Install

Attempted OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat)
Desktop Image: 64-bit (AMD64)
GNU GRUB: version 2.12

Installation Details

Disk setup: Erase disk and install Ubuntu
Installation disk: WDC WD10... sda
Applications: Default selection
Disc encryption: None
Proprietary software: Codecs & drivers
Partitions

partition sda1 formatted as fat32 used for /boot/efi
partition sda2 formatted as ext4 used for /



Computer Details

Product Name: Aspire E5-574G
Manufacturer: Acer
CPU Type: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
System BIOS Version: V.1.14
F12 Boot Menu: [Enabled]
Supervisor Password: Set
Secure Boot: [Enabled]
Boot Mode: UEFI
Boot Priority Order:

HDD
USB HDD
USB FDD
ATAPI CDROM
....
(option 8) EFI File Boot 0: Yes



I can get through the entire install with no issues. This is not a dual boot, I want to run this Ubuntu install as the primary OS. When attempting to reboot after successful install, I get to a screen that tells me to "remove bootable medium and press ENTER". At this point, the computer restarts and then cannot boot. The only option that is available is "1. Yes".
I have visited ACER forums and have not seen a solution for this. Same problems manifests with older LTS versions of Ubuntu, and with Linux Mint Cinnamon 22.

All Acer require you to enable "trust" on the UEFI boot entry. Make sure you have latest available UEFI firmware. Aspire V 15 Nitro Trust settings required.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518065/dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-in-acer-no-grub-showing-up
Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947

That ended up solving the issue. I had to enter the UEFI security settings, set the supervisor password, go into the subnames for HDD0 until I reached shimx64.efi, and press ENTER on it (optionally rename it) and save and exit. Thanks a bunch!
