After installing Ubuntu and turning on my laptop it shows something like "no bootable device detected, insert bootable media
I'm a new user to Linux. I've tried installing Ubuntu on my old Acer Aspire 5830T laptop. The files of Ubuntu are there in the SSD, but the laptop won't detect it.
Also there is no option to change to uefi boot in my bios

You've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're asking. How you wrote the ISO also matters too, and a Ubuntu ISO will install correctly to legacy (CSM), uEFI and modern Secure-boot uEFI if written as documented; however if you reformat ISO during write with options a failure to boot is expected if you didn't use the correct options for your intended hardware, but you've not said what ISO you used; nor how it was written to install media etc.

Did you enable Trust on the unknown entry that really is "ubuntu"? All Acers. Aspire V 15 Nitro Trust settings required. 2024
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518065/dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-in-acer-no-grub-showing-up
Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx

I was trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 and I made the bootable drive with Mbr and legacy (but my disk is gpt) I previously had windows 10 installed I used erase disk and install option but when it reboot and told me to remove installation media and hit enter there would appear an blue screen of windows saying something like your computer needs to be repaired and that important files are not found

After that I tried to install again but it didn't work so I used an windows bootable usb and opened cmd and cleaned formatted all the disks and then the no bootable device detected insert bootable media and hit enter

A direct clone of the ISO to your install media is best; as that will allow you to install on legacy devices, uEFI & modern Secure-boot uEFI.  If you used options to modify ISO during write (ie. you specified parameters instead of them coming from the ISO itself) the installer can fail to operate as expected as its not seeing what it expects to see; usually detected by failure to boot (bootloader written to wrong device); that is expected as user didn't write ISO correctly (as per docs; or use options that match their hardware). You only mention release (24.04) but not which ISO/installer

Did you install it in legacy mode? Sometimes you need to change to UEFI mode on bios, I did it for my lenovo laptop and it worked.
To access your BIOS, try pressing F2, F10 or SUPR while the laptop is turning on. Each model has different key to access BIOs, but usually it's the SUPR one.
EDIT: if you edit your question and add specific data as your laptop model, ubuntu version, how did you install it (usb, CD, etc) we can help you better.
