Ubuntu install fails on Acer Aspire ES1-531
I am trying to install Ububtu on an Acer aspire ES1-531.  I chose the option to install Ubuntu and erase the original Windows operating system. Everything proceeds as expected until the point where the Ubuntu installer directs that the bootable USB is removed and the laptop is ready to reboot. The machine gets to the ACER splash screen and then the message "reset system" appears momentarily top left of a black screen. The laptop shuts down and immediately repeats this process in a loop - restarts, splash screen, reset system message, shut down, restarts etc.
F2 still works on restart and everything in the options there seems normal. UEFI boot enabled.
Has anyone experienced this and found how to deal with it? Any ideas?

All Acer require you to enable "trust" on the ubuntu UEFI boot entry in UEFI settings. Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx Acer Aspire ES1-512-C39M Details on supervisor password and settings to enable trust on ubuntu entries Also R14 model same fix
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 & Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Thank you. I'll take a good look at all that.
