Installing Ubuntu (dual boot windows 10 setup) on Acer Aspire 3
I am trying to install Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 10) on my Acer laptop
I have a 2TB SATA HD with 1 TB specially for Ubuntu
I formatted it using Rufus (for some reason Balena Etcher just isn't working)
I have flashed an iso of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a USB drive (earlier tried doing with another USB drive but tried the second one just in case)
I am able to go to Ubuntu but my installation for Ubuntu just won't start
Please find screenshots attached
I am new to all this but learning and any help would be much appreciated
I am getting the error as per screenshots attached
I am putting a Google Drive link here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19lOanTa44P8Q1tc83fDJSGqUVMntUgHl?usp=share_link

All Acer require user to set "trust" on ubuntu entry in UEFI settings. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 &
Trust
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx

There are no options like trust on ubuntu entry in UEFI settings here

I got the option for Acer trust setting but that happened only when I switched from legacy to UEFI. And once I got the option I was not able to see any HDD after entering the UEFI trust setting

Do you have drive set to AHCI mode? If you turned UEFI Secure Boot on to set trust, but previously installed with Secure Boot off, then you need to turn it back off. Also if you set UEFI password never forget it or reset to blank or you may brick system. More Acer UEFI info: Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

I have noted down the passwords. In Main (in BIOS) the SATA Mode shown is ACHI. I tried installing with secure boot off but it still won't work. I have shared more images on the Google drive link above (and given permissions)

If at Ubuntu@ubuntu that is live installer. You may need to redo live installer & verify download.

I didn't understand. You mean I would have download the live installer again and verify download? I already did checksum with this installer. I made an iso of it on a USB drive after verification

If you updated & verified ISO, then that should be good. Did you get system to install or not? Some have issues with one port or the other, some with one flash drive but not another, and some like you with different installers. Do not know why. If live installer works in live mode, then install should work. I use Kubuntu have have not had any issues.

I will try downloading the ISO again. This is already my second USB drive. It is working in the sense, I can try Ubuntu! What I am not able to do is install it!

I had a few questions. Is it possible Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is not compatible with my Acer Aspire 3 PC? I tried with ‘Select an UEFI File as trusted’ and typed in WindowsBootManager. I keep getting subiquity error and so I looked it up - Subiquity is an installer framework for Ubuntu. It provides the Ubuntu Server with a text-based installation user interface and Ubuntu Core first-boot configuration. Subiquity is also the back end for the Ubuntu Desktop installer.
This is what I got

Did you go thru the first comments and make sure UEFI/BIOS settings are correct, usually require changes. I could not install Ubuntu on my 2006 laptop as specs too low, server installed & added lightweight gui. But was surprised Kubuntu installed but bit slow. It did work better with Kubuntu on external SSD.If you boot in UEFI mode & run in live mode, then system is UEFI.You set "trust" on an "unknown" entry after install as it really is the ubuntu entry. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
